# HTACCESS Query String doesn't work anymore

Tags: php, .htaccess

I' am using this code block below in HTACCESS for Custom PHP Website. When I echo the p1 variable on the script I get values like:

> album/mix-master-38

Whereas the value of p1 should have been only

> album

When I echo out p2 value its blank, the value of p2 value should have been

> mix-master-38

HTACCESS

```
        Options +FollowSymlinks

        ## Mod_rewrite in use.
        RewriteEngine on

        ## Prevent Directory Listing
        IndexIgnore *

        # ---- Make pages render without their extension in the url
        Options +MultiViews

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)|([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+))$ ./index.php?p1=$1&p2=$2&p3=$3&p4=$4&p5=$5 [L]
        RewriteRule ^(.*/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)|([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+))$ ./index.php?p1=$1&p2=$2&p3=$3&p4=$4 [L]
        RewriteRule ^(.*/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)|([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+))$ ./index.php?p1=$1&p2=$2&p3=$3 [L]
        RewriteRule ^(.*/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)|([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+))$ ./index.php?p1=$1&p2=$2 [L]
        RewriteRule ^(.*/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)|([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+))$ ./index.php?p1=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.*` at the beginning of your regex is matching the *album* part. To capture it separately you could put that in parenthesis, so you'd have: `^((.*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)|([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+))$`

Note that this change will shift the offset, so you may want to either change $1 -> $2 and so on, or make the outside parenthesis non-capturing.